# Install Silently CCleaner without Chrome

Tags: windows, installation, google-chrome, silent

Im building an AutoIt script and I want to run the installation of CCleaner in silent mode ("ccleaner_installer.exe /S") but this installs Google Chrome by default, which I DONT want. What could I do?

Thanks!

Comment: When you do please add details like as links and how you found it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a "CCleaner Slim" version, that doesn't include any extra stuff

http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner/download/slim